# Blender mist pass final render looks darker than viewport

Tags: rendering, eevee-render-engine

No other special settings, just create new default file and enable mist pass then I got this result.

[image: final render]

[image: viewport view]

Answer (score 0):

Just change color management view Transform to Raw. Seems mist pass wont apply the filmic color filter.